# Where to store search matches in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am writing an app in cakephp that will perform scheduled searches for users and store the search results in a `matches` table.  My question is do I really need this `matches` model in cakephp to store the results?  If the answer is no, how should I store the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy new year.

There are many ways to store data and the one you choose will depend on the data itself and the use to which it will be put (and when it will be used). Because you are doing scheduled searches, I assume that the user may not be around when the search is done, in which case the result needs to be stored.

In this case, I'd use the database. If you need to keep historical results this is definitely the way to go. If the results can be overwritten, you could use a text file per user, but that might get messy.

You don't need to use the main database - you could have another MySql, for example or even a totally different one such as a flat file db.

What would I do? I'd use a table in the main database and get on with something else.